# Use collect_list and collect_set in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

According to the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$), the `collect_set` and `collect_list` functions should be available in Spark SQL. However, I cannot get it to work. I'm running Spark 1.6.0 using a [Docker image](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark).

I'm trying to do this in Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 

df.groupBy("column1") 
  .agg(collect_set("column2")) 
  .show()
```

And receive the following error at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function collect_set;
```

Also tried it using `pyspark`, but it also fails. The docs state these functions are aliases of Hive UDAFs, but I can't figure out to enable these functions.

How to fix this? Thanx!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Spark 2.0+**:

[SPARK-10605](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10605) introduced native `collect_list` and `collect_set` implementation. `SparkSession` with Hive support or `HiveContext` are no longer required.

**Spark 2.0-SNAPSHOT** *(before 2016-05-03)*:

You have to enable Hive support for a given `SparkSession`:

In Scala:

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("testing")
  .enableHiveSupport()  // <- enable Hive support.
  .getOrCreate()
```

In Python:

```py
spark = (SparkSession.builder
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate())
```

**Spark < 2.0**:

To be able to use Hive UDFs (see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) you have use Spark built with Hive support (this is already covered when you use pre-built binaries what seems to be the case here) and initialize `SparkContext` using `HiveContext`.

In Scala:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

val sqlContext: SQLContext = new HiveContext(sc)
```

In Python:

```py
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
```

Comment: and what about 1.6.1
in documents it sais that avialable "@since 1.6.0" but I'm still getting that error

Comment: Hey @zero323, I'm trying to use the 'collect_list' function in Spark 1.5.0. I've created the hive context, but can't figure out how to import the function. This doesn't compile: .groupBy(providerData("PRVSEQ"), providerData("PROV_NUM"))
      .agg(collect_list(regexp_replace(triggerReport("match_type"), "_(Individual|Practice)Model.", "")))

Comment: @VijayRatnagiri It has been introduced in 1.6. As far as I remember you should be able to use raw SQL query in 1.5 on registered temporary table.

Comment: @KhachaturStepanyan In 1.6 you still need Hive support.