# pyspark collect_set or collect_list with groupby

Tags: list, group-by, set, pyspark, collect

How can I use `collect_set` or `collect_list` on a dataframe after `groupby`. for example: `df.groupby('key').collect_set('values')`. I get an error: `AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'collect_set'`

Comment: Can you post some sample data that will throw this error so that we can debug your issue?

Comment: in pyspark it works fine, btw I am trying precisely to translate this work in scala spark https://johnpaton.net/posts/forward-fill-spark/ (I mean the scoop of the job is backfilling and forward filling and this is how it works in pyspark)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You need to use agg. Example:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

sc = SparkContext("local")

sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("a", None, None),
    ("a", "code1", None),
    ("a", "code2", "name2"),
], ["id", "code", "name"])

df.show()

+---+-----+-----+
| id| code| name|
+---+-----+-----+
|  a| null| null|
|  a|code1| null|
|  a|code2|name2|
+---+-----+-----+
```

Note in the above you have to create a HiveContext. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35529093/690430 for dealing with different Spark versions.

```py
(df
  .groupby("id")
  .agg(F.collect_set("code"),
       F.collect_list("name"))
  .show())

+---+-----------------+------------------+
| id|collect_set(code)|collect_list(name)|
+---+-----------------+------------------+
|  a|   [code1, code2]|           [name2]|
+---+-----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: collect_set()  contains distinct elements   and collect_list()   contains all elements (except nulls)

Comment: size function on collect_set or collect_list will be better to calculate the count value or  to use plain count function . I am using an window to get the count of transaction attached to an account.

Comment: How to have the output of collect_list as dict when i have multiple columns inside list eg : agg(collect_list(struct(df.f1,df.f2,df.f3))). Output should be [f1:value,f2:value,f3:value] for each group.

Comment: While performing this on large dataframe, collect_set does not seem to get me correct values of a group. Any thoughts?

Answer (score -5):

If your dataframe is large, you can try using [pandas udf(GROUPED_AGG)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf) to avoid memory error. It is also much faster.

> Grouped aggregate Pandas UDFs are similar to Spark aggregate functions. Grouped aggregate Pandas UDFs are used with groupBy().agg() and pyspark.sql.Window. It defines an aggregation from one or more pandas.Series to a scalar value, where each pandas.Series represents a column within the group or window. [pandas udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#pandas-udfs-aka-vectorized-udfs)

example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

@F.pandas_udf('string', F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def collect_list(name):
    return ', '.join(name)

grouped_df = df.groupby('id').agg(collect_list(df["name"]).alias('names'))
```

Comment: I do not think a custom UDF is faster than a spark builtin

Comment: I _know_ that a pandas UDF is way slower than a spark builtin (and also, that a pandas UDF requires more memory from your cluster)! What's faster, pure java/scala, or java that has to call python on a data structure that also has to be serialized via arrow into a pandas DF?