# How to retrieve all columns using pyspark collect_list functions

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a pyspark 2.0.1. I'm trying to groupby my data frame & retrieve the value for all the fields from my data frame. I found that

```
z=data1.groupby('country').agg(F.collect_list('names'))
```

will give me values for country & names attribute & for names attribute it will give column header as `collect_list(names)`. But for my job I have dataframe with around 15 columns & I will run a loop & will change the groupby field each time inside loop & need the output for all of the remaining fields.Can you please suggest me how to do it using collect_list() or any other pyspark functions?

I tried this code too

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
fieldnames=data1.schema.names 
names1= list() 
for item in names: 
   if item != 'names': 
     names1.append(item) 
 z=data1.groupby('names').agg(F.collect_list(names1)) 
 z.show()
```

but got error message

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method collect_list([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
```

Comment: I tried this code `from pyspark.sql import functions as F
fieldnames=data1.schema.names
names1= list()
for item in names:
    if item != 'names':
        names1.append(item)   
        #print item

z=data1.groupby('names').agg(F.collect_list(names1))
z.show()` but got error message `Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method collect_list([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist`

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: *please*, do not post code in the comments space! kindly update your post to include the code snippet

Answer (score 9):

Use struct to combine the columns before calling groupBy

suppose you have a dataframe

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([(0,1,2),(0,4,5),(1,7,8),(1,8,7)])).toDF("a","b","c")

df = df.select("a", f.struct(["b","c"]).alias("newcol"))
df.show()
+---+------+
|  a|newcol|
+---+------+
|  0| [1,2]|
|  0| [4,5]|
|  1| [7,8]|
|  1| [8,7]|
+---+------+
df = df.groupBy("a").agg(f.collect_list("newcol").alias("collected_col"))
df.show()
+---+--------------+
|  a| collected_col|
+---+--------------+
|  0|[[1,2], [4,5]]|
|  1|[[7,8], [8,7]]|
+---+--------------+
```

Aggregation operation can be done only on single columns.

After aggregation, You can collect the result and iterate over it to separate the combined columns generate the index dict. or you can write a
udf to separate the combined columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
def foo(x):
    x1 = [y[0] for y in x]
    x2 = [y[1] for y in x]
    return(x1,x2)

st = StructType([StructField("b", ArrayType(LongType())), StructField("c", ArrayType(LongType()))])
udf_foo = udf(foo, st)
df = df.withColumn("ncol", 
                  udf_foo("collected_col")).select("a",
                  col("ncol").getItem("b").alias("b"), 
                  col("ncol").getItem("c").alias("c"))
df.show()

+---+------+------+
|  a|     b|     c|
+---+------+------+
|  0|[1, 4]|[2, 5]|
|  1|[7, 8]|[8, 7]|
+---+------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ashwinids.But I my b & c column should be identified separately along with column a,not the collected_col by combining b & c

Comment: Actually I'm trying this because of my question mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791254/typeerror-groupeddata-object-is-not-iterable-in-pyspark/46791488?noredirect=1#comment80541321_46791488)

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Thank you ashwinids. I'm getting error message that StructType is not defined

Comment: Add `from pyspark.sql.types import *` line at the top to import datatypes

Answer (score 3):

Actually we can do it in pyspark 2.2 .

First we need create a constant column ("Temp"), groupBy with that column ("Temp") and apply agg by pass iterable *exprs in which expression of collect_list exits.

Below is the code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as ftions
import functools as ftools

def groupColumnData(df, columns):
      df = df.withColumn("Temp", ftions.lit(1))
      exprs = [ftions.collect_list(colName) for colName in columns]
      df = df.groupby('Temp').agg(*exprs)
      df = df.drop("Temp")
      df = df.toDF(*columns)
      return df
```

Input Data:

```
df.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|
|  0|  4|  5|
|  1|  7|  8|
|  1|  8|  7|
+---+---+---+
```

Output Data:

```
df.show()

    +------------+------------+------------+
    |           a|           b|           c|
    +------------+------------+------------+
    |[0, 0, 1, 1]|[1, 4, 7, 8]|[2, 5, 8, 7]|
    +------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

in spark 2.4.4 and python 3.7 (I guess its also relevant for previous spark and python version) --
My suggestion is a based on [pauli's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117331/pauli) answer,
instead of creating the struct **and then** using the agg function, create the struct **inside** collect_list:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0,1,2),(0,4,5),(1,7,8),(1,8,7)]).toDF("a","b","c")
df.groupBy("a").agg(collect_list(struct(["b","c"])).alias("res")).show()
```

result :

```
+---+-----------------+
|  a|res              |
+---+-----------------+
|  0|[[1, 2], [4, 5]] |
|  1|[[7, 8], [8, 7]] |
+---+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use Concat_ws function it's perfectly fine.

```
> from pyspark.sql.functions import * df =
> spark.createDataFrame([(0,1,2),(0,4,5),(1,7,8),(1,8,7)]).toDF("a","b","c")
> df.groupBy('a').agg(collect_list(concat_ws(',','b','c'))).alias('r').show()
```

[image]