# Include null values in collect_list in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to include null values in `collect_list` while using `pyspark`, however the `collect_list` operation excludes `nulls`. I have looked into the following post [Pypsark - Retain null values when using collect_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395458/pypsark-retain-null-values-when-using-collect-list?noredirect=1&lq=1) . However, the answer given is not what I am looking for.

I have a dataframe `df` like this.

```
| id | family | date       |
----------------------------
| 1  |  Prod  | null       |
| 2  |  Dev   | 2019-02-02 |
| 3  |  Prod  | 2017-03-08 |
```

Here's my code so far:

`df.groupby("family").agg(f.collect_list("date").alias("entry_date"))`

This gives me an output like this:

```
| family | date       |
-----------------------
| Prod   |[2017-03-08]|
| Dev    |[2019-02-02]|
```

What I really want is as follows:

```
| family | date             |
-----------------------------
| Prod   |[null, 2017-03-08]|
| Dev    |[2019-02-02]      |
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround for this could be to replace all null-values with another value. (Perhaps not the best way to do this, but it's a solution nonetheless)

```
df = df.na.fill("my_null") # Replace null with "my_null"
df = df.groupby("family").agg(f.collect_list("date").alias("entry_date"))
```

Should give you:

```
| family | date             |
-----------------------------
| Prod   |[my_null, 2017-03-08]|
| Dev    |[2019-02-02]      |
```