# How to return a list of double in a Pyspark UDF?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

`from pyspark.sql import functions as func`

I have a Pyspark Dataframe, which is called `df`.  It has the following schema:

```
id: string
item: string
data: double
```

I apply on it the following operation:

```
grouped_df = df.groupBy(["id", "item"]).agg(func.collect_list(df.data).alias("dataList"))
```

Also, i defined the user defined function `iqrOnList`:

```
@udf
def iqrOnList(accumulatorsList: list):
  import numpy as np 

  Q1 = np.percentile(accumulatorsList, 25)
  Q3 = np.percentile(accumulatorsList, 75) 
  IQR = Q3 - Q1

  lowerFence = Q1 - (1.5 * IQR)
  upperFence = Q3 + (1.5 * IQR)

  return [elem if (elem >= lowerFence and elem <= upperFence) else None for elem in accumulatorsList]
```

I used this UDF in this way:

```
grouped_df = grouped_df.withColumn("SecondList", iqrOnList(grouped_df.dataList))
```

Those operations return in output the dataframe `grouped_df`, which is like this:

```
id: string
item: string
dataList: array
SecondList: string
```

**Problem**:

`SecondList` has exactly the correct value i expect (for example `[1, 2, 3, null, 3, null, 2]`), but with the wrong return type (`string` instead of `array`, even though it keeps the form of it).

The problem is I need it to be stored as an `array`, exactly as `dataList` is.

**Questions:**

1) How can i save it with the correct type?

2) This UDF is expensive in term of performance. 
I read [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html) that Pandas UDF's performance are way better than common UDF. What is the equivalent of this method in Pandas UDF?

**Bonus question (less priority):** `func.collect_list(df.data)` does not collect `null` values, which `df.data` has. I'd like to collect them too, how can i do without [replacing all null values with another default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135151/include-null-values-in-collect-list-in-pyspark)?

Comment: When you define a `udf` you have to specify the return type, otherwise it will default to `StringType`. You probably want `ArrayType(DoubleType())`

Answer (score 1):

You can still use your current syntax, just need to provide return type in annotation declaration

```
import pyspark.sql.types as Types
@udf(returnType=Types.ArrayType(Types.DoubleType()))
```

Comment: That solved the type issue. Do you know how to write that UDF as a Pandas UDF?