# Sample values in Aggreagte

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data set where I need to get some counts and also the most frequent values.

An example data frame is below.

```python
from pyspark.sql import Row, functions as F    
row = Row("UK_1","UK_2","Request_Date",'Approval_Date',"Cat",'Country','State' )
test_df = (sc.parallelize
([
    row(1,1,'12/10/2016','10-10-2017',"A",'USA','NY'),
    row(1,2,None,'10-1-2016','A','CAN','QC'),
    row(2,1,'14/10/2016',None,'B','USA','FL'),
    row('A',3,'!~2016/2/276','Bad Date','B','USA',None),
    row(None,1,'26/09/2016','26/11/08','A',None,'ON'),
    row(1,1,'12/10/2016','22-02-20','A',None,None),
    row(1,2,None,'45/45/00','A','MEX','XPZ'),
    row(2,1,'14/10/2016','None','B','DEU','DUS'),
    row(None,None,'!~2016/2/276','12-01-2015','B','',''),
    row(None,1,'26/09/2016',None,'A','USA','CA')
]).toDF())
test_df.show()
```

[image]

I have sample code but not complete.

```python
(
    test_df
    .agg
    (
        F.count('*').alias('count'),
        F.countDistinct('Country').alias('distinct_country')
        #.alias('top_2_countries')
    )
    .show()
)
```

The results expected is like below.

[image]

How to get this done.

Comment: @pault , The most frequent occurring values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `null` values in your DataFrame are causing problems for aggregating. One option is to replace those values with something not-null for the purposes of aggregation.

For instance:

```python
new_df = test_df.withColumn(
    "Country",
    F.when(
        F.isnull("Country"),
        "None"
    ).otherwise(F.col("Country"))
)
```

This returns a DataFrame where the `null` values of the `Country` column have been replaced with the string `"None"`. (I purposely avoided using the string `"null"` to avoid ambiguity.)

Now you can get the counts and rank each of the Countries by their frequencies using [`pyspark.sql.functions.rank()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.rank) and a [`pyspark.sql.Window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window).

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
new_df.groupBy("Country")\
    .agg(
        F.count("Country").alias("Count"),
        F.rank().over(Window.orderBy(F.count("Country").desc())).alias("Rank")
    )\
    .show()
#+-------+-----+----+
#|Country|Count|Rank|
#+-------+-----+----+
#|    USA|    4|   1|
#|   None|    2|   2|
#|    MEX|    1|   3|
#|       |    1|   3|
#|    DEU|    1|   3|
#|    CAN|    1|   3|
#+-------+-----+----+
```

As you can see, `"None"` shows up in the County column because of the replacement. At this point, you have everything you need to compute the desired aggregations.

- The first output column (`count`) is simply the sum of the `Count` column.
- The second output column (`distinct_country`) is computed similarly to how you were doing so in your post.
- The final output column (`top_2_countries`) can be computed by using [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list), filtering for values where the `rank <= 2`.

For example:

```python
new_df.groupBy("Country")\
    .agg(
        F.count("Country").alias("Count"),
        F.rank().over(Window.orderBy(F.count("Country").desc())).alias("Rank")
    )\
    .agg(
        F.sum("Count").alias("count"),
        F.countDistinct("Country").alias("distinct_country"),
        F.collect_list(F.when(F.col("rank")<=2, F.col("Country"))).alias("top_2_countries")
    )\
    .show()
#+-----+----------------+---------------+
#|count|distinct_country|top_2_countries|
#+-----+----------------+---------------+
#|   10|               6|    [USA, None]|
#+-----+----------------+---------------+
```

Note two things here. Firstly the count is 6 as opposed to 5 in your example. The 5 is a result of `null`s being ignored in `countDistinct()`. Similarly, the `top_2_countries` column has the values `[USA, None]`.

For demostration purposes, here is what would have happened if you had converted the `"None"` values back into `null`:

```python
new_df.groupBy("Country")\
    .agg(
        F.count("Country").alias("Count"),
        F.rank().over(Window.orderBy(F.count("Country").desc())).alias("Rank")
    )\
    .withColumn(
        "Country",
        F.when(F.col("Country") == "None", None).otherwise(F.col("Country"))
    )\
    .agg(
        F.sum("Count").alias("count"),
        F.countDistinct("Country").alias("distinct_country"),
        F.collect_list(F.when(F.col("rank")<=2, F.col("Country"))).alias("top_2_countries")
    )\
    .show()
#+-----+----------------+---------------+
#|count|distinct_country|top_2_countries|
#+-----+----------------+---------------+
#|   10|               5|          [USA]|
#+-----+----------------+---------------+
```

As you can see the distinct count is 5, but the `top_2_countries` column does not contain `null`. This is because `null` is excluded from `collect_list()`<sup>1</sup>. (See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580782/pyspark-collect-set-or-collect-list-with-groupby/38063180)).

<sup>1</sup>**It is important to note that I have exploited this fact in calling `collect_list()`.** From the docs for [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when):

> If Column.otherwise() is not invoked, None is returned for unmatched conditions.