# Create new pyspark DataFrame column by concatenating values of another column based on a conditional

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in `pyspark` like below

```python
df.show()

+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
| Dev_No|               model|              Tested|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
|BTA16C5|          Windows PC|                   N|
|BTA16C5|                 SRL|                   N|
|BTA16C5|     Hewlett Packard|                   N|
|CTA16C5|     Android Devices|                   Y|
|CTA16C5|     Hewlett Packard|                   N|
|4MY16A5|               Other|                   N|
|4MY16A5|               Other|                   N|
|4MY16A5|              Tablet|                   Y|
|4MY16A5|               Other|                   N|
|4MY16A5|           Cable STB|                   Y|
|4MY16A5|               Other|                   N|
|4MY16A5|          Windows PC|                   Y|
|4MY16A5|          Windows PC|                   Y|
|4MY16A5|         Smart Watch|                   Y|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Now using the above data frame I want to create the below data frame with a `newcolumn` called `Tested_devices` and populate the column with values where for each `Dev_No` select `model` where `Tested` is `Y` and populate all the values as comma separated.

```python
df1.show()

+-------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Dev_No|               model|              Tested|                                        Tested_devices|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|BTA16C5|          Windows PC|                   N|                                                      |
|BTA16C5|                 SRL|                   N|                                                      |  
|BTA16C5|     Hewlett Packard|                   N|                                                      |
|CTA16C5|     Android Devices|                   Y|                                       Android Devices|
|CTA16C5|     Hewlett Packard|                   N|                                                      |      
|4MY16A5|               Other|                   N|                                                      |
|4MY16A5|               Other|                   N|                                                      |
|4MY16A5|              Tablet|                   Y| Tablet, Cable STB,Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch| 
|4MY16A5|               Other|                   N|                                                      |
|4MY16A5|           Cable STB|                   Y| Tablet, Cable STB,Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
|4MY16A5|               Other|                   N|                                                      |
|4MY16A5|          Windows PC|                   Y| Tablet, Cable STB,Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
|4MY16A5|          Windows PC|                   Y| Tablet, Cable STB,Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
|4MY16A5|         Smart Watch|                   Y| Tablet, Cable STB,Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried something like below to select `Dev_No` and `model` where `Tested` is `Y`

```python
a = df.select("Dev_No", "model"), when(df.Tested == 'Y')
```

I am unable to get the result. It gave me below error

```python
TypeError: when() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

How can I achieve what I want

Comment: Do you need the Dev_No to repeat in the output?  An easier solution could be to filter to only the tested devices then group on the Dev_No and collected the models as a list:

Comment: The error in what you tried is that you should use where to filter the dataframe: `a = df.where(df.Tested == 'Y').select("Dev_No", "model")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

For spark 1.6, you will need an alternative approach. One way to do this without using a `udf` or any `Window` functions is to create a second temporary DataFrame with the collected values and then join this back to the original DataFrame.

First group by *both* `Dev_No` and `Tested` and aggregate using `concat_ws` and `collect_list`. After aggregation, filter the DataFrame for tested devices only.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# create temporary DataFrame
df2 = df.groupBy('Dev_No', 'Tested')\
    .agg(f.concat_ws(", ", f.collect_list('model')).alias('Tested_devices'))\
    .where(f.col('Tested') == 'Y')

df2.show(truncate=False)
#+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
#|Dev_No |Tested|Tested_devices                                        |
#+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
#|CTA16C5|Y     |Android Devices                                       |
#|4MY16A5|Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now do a left join of `df` with `df2` using both the `Dev_No` and `Tested` columns as the join keys:

```python
df.join(df2, on=['Dev_No', 'Tested'], how='left')\
    .select('Dev_No', 'model', 'Tested', 'Tested_devices')\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

The purpose of using the `select` at the end is to get the columns in the same order as the original DataFrame for display purposes- you can remove this step if you choose.

This will result in the following output (same output as below (with the `concat_ws`):

```python
#+-------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
#|Dev_No |model          |Tested|Tested_devices                                        |
#+-------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |null                                                  |
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |null                                                  |
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |null                                                  |
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |null                                                  |
#|CTA16C5|Hewlett Packard|N     |null                                                  |
#|BTA16C5|Windows PC     |N     |null                                                  |
#|BTA16C5|SRL            |N     |null                                                  |
#|BTA16C5|Hewlett Packard|N     |null                                                  |
#|CTA16C5|Android Devices|Y     |Android Devices                                       |
#|4MY16A5|Tablet         |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#|4MY16A5|Cable STB      |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#|4MY16A5|Windows PC     |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#|4MY16A5|Windows PC     |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#|4MY16A5|Smart Watch    |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#+-------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

**Original Answer**: (For later versions of Spark)

You can achieve this by using two [`pyspark.sql.functions.when()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) statements- one of them within a call to [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) over a [`Window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window), taking advantage of the fact that the default `null` value [does not get added to the list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38063180/5858851):

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.select(
    "*",
    f.when(
        f.col("Tested") == "Y",
        f.collect_list(
            f.when(
                f.col("Tested") == "Y",
                f.col('model')
            )
        ).over(Window.partitionBy("Dev_No"))
    ).alias("Tested_devices")
).show(truncate=False)
#+-------+---------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
#|Dev_No |model          |Tested|Tested_devices                                          |
#+-------+---------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
#|BTA16C5|Windows PC     |N     |null                                                    |
#|BTA16C5|SRL            |N     |null                                                    |
#|BTA16C5|Hewlett Packard|N     |null                                                    |
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |null                                                    |
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |null                                                    |
#|4MY16A5|Tablet         |Y     |[Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch]|
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |null                                                    |
#|4MY16A5|Cable STB      |Y     |[Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch]|
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |null                                                    |
#|4MY16A5|Windows PC     |Y     |[Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch]|
#|4MY16A5|Windows PC     |Y     |[Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch]|
#|4MY16A5|Smart Watch    |Y     |[Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch]|
#|CTA16C5|Android Devices|Y     |[Android Devices]                                       |
#|CTA16C5|Hewlett Packard|N     |null                                                    |
#+-------+---------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

If instead you wanted your output exactly as you showed in your question- as a string of comma separated values instead of a list and empty strings instead of `null`- you could modify this slightly as follows:

Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) to concatenate the output of `collect_list` into a string. I'm using `", "` as the separator. This is equivalent to doing `", ".join(some_list)` in python. Next, we add a `.otherwise(f.lit(""))` to the end of the outer `when()` call to specify that we want to return a literal empty string if the condition is `False`.

```python
df.select(
    "*",
    f.when(
        f.col("Tested") == "Y",
        f.concat_ws(
            ", ",
            f.collect_list(
                f.when(
                    f.col("Tested") == "Y",
                    f.col('model')
                )
            ).over(Window.partitionBy("Dev_No"))
        )
    ).otherwise(f.lit("")).alias("Tested_devices")
).show(truncate=False)
#+-------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
#|Dev_No |model          |Tested|Tested_devices                                        |
#+-------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
#|BTA16C5|Windows PC     |N     |                                                      |
#|BTA16C5|SRL            |N     |                                                      |
#|BTA16C5|Hewlett Packard|N     |                                                      |
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |                                                      |
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |                                                      |
#|4MY16A5|Tablet         |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |                                                      |
#|4MY16A5|Cable STB      |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |                                                      |
#|4MY16A5|Windows PC     |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#|4MY16A5|Windows PC     |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#|4MY16A5|Smart Watch    |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
#|CTA16C5|Android Devices|Y     |Android Devices                                       |
#|CTA16C5|Hewlett Packard|N     |                                                      |
#+-------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Using `pyspark-sql` syntax, the first example above is equivalent to:

```python
df.registerTempTable("df")
query = """
 SELECT *, 
        CASE 
          WHEN Tested = 'Y' 
          THEN COLLECT_LIST(
            CASE 
              WHEN Tested = 'Y' 
              THEN model
            END
          ) OVER (PARTITION BY Dev_No) 
        END AS Tested_devices
   FROM df
"""
sqlCtx.sql(query).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: I am getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: 'collect_list(CASE WHEN ('Tested = Y) THEN 'model) is not supported in a window operation` error

Comment: What version of spark?

Comment: my version is spark 1.6

Comment: @user9367133 I made an update at the top that should work for 1.6

Comment: There is also [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set) if you want to remove duplicates from the list.

Answer (score 1):

commented for clarity and explanation

## pyspark > 1.6

```
#window function to group by Dev_No
from pyspark.sql import Window
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Dev_No")

from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
#udf function to change the collected list to string and also to check if Tested column is Y or N
@f.udf(t.StringType())
def populatedUdfFunc(tested, list):
    if(tested == "Y"):
        return ", ".join(list)
    else:
        return ""
#collecting models when Tested is Y using window function defined above
df.withColumn("Tested_devices", populatedUdfFunc(f.col("Tested"), f.collect_list(f.when(f.col("Tested") == "Y", f.col("model")).otherwise(None)).over(windowSpec))).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+-------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
|Dev_No |model          |Tested|Tested_devices                                        |
+-------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
|BTA16C5|Windows PC     |N     |                                                      |
|BTA16C5|SRL            |N     |                                                      |
|BTA16C5|Hewlett Packard|N     |                                                      |
|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |                                                      |
|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |                                                      |
|4MY16A5|Tablet         |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |                                                      |
|4MY16A5|Cable STB      |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
|4MY16A5|Other          |N     |                                                      |
|4MY16A5|Windows PC     |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
|4MY16A5|Windows PC     |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
|4MY16A5|Smart Watch    |Y     |Tablet, Cable STB, Windows PC, Windows PC, Smart Watch|
|CTA16C5|Android Devices|Y     |Android Devices                                       |
|CTA16C5|Hewlett Packard|N     |                                                      |
+-------+---------------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

## spark = 1.6

for pyspark 1.6, `collect_list` won't work with `window` function and there is *no collect_list function defined in SqlContext*. So you will have to *do without window function and use HiveContext instead of SQLContext*

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import types as t
#udf function to change the collected list to string and also to check if Tested column is Y or N
def populatedUdfFunc(list):
    return ", ".join(list)

populateUdf = f.udf(populatedUdfFunc, t.StringType())

#collecting models when Tested is Y using window function defined above
tempdf = df.groupBy("Dev_No").agg(populateUdf(f.collect_list(f.when(f.col("Tested") == "Y", f.col("model")).otherwise(None))).alias("Tested_devices"))
df.join(
    tempdf,
    (df["Dev_No"] == tempdf["Dev_No"]) & (df["Tested"] == f.lit("Y")), "left").show(truncate=False)
```

You would get the same output as above