# Combine two columns values in one Spark- Python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this table bellow:

```
FrameForm | Sections | Framefrom_section | FrameFrom_echelon
----------|----------|-------------------|------------------
70        |  11/12   |       11/12       |      50004
70        |  13/14   |       13/14       |      60003
```

How can I do a test via `pySpark` on a `FrameFrom` column to combine the two values of `Framefrom_section` and `FrameFrom_echelon` to obtain this result:

```
FrameForm | Framefrom_section | FrameFrom_echelon
----------|-------------------|------------------
70        | [11/12,13/14]     |    [50004,60003]
```

Comment: `from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list` and then do `new_df = df.groupBy("FrameForm").agg(*[collect_list(c).alias(c) for c in ["Framefrom_section", "FrameFrom_echelon"])` .. looking for a dupe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pyspark collect\_set or collect\_list with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580782/pyspark-collect-set-or-collect-list-with-groupby)