# difference between 'groupby.apply' and 'groupby.agg'

Tags: pyspark

What's difference between '`groupby.apply'and'groupby.agg`'? , Why processed data are displayed as 'NoneType'？

1. This is for Spark 2.1.0，I want to turn a column into multiple rows，same column can be connected with commas，when I use `groupby.apply`, there are no output, when I use `groupby.agg`, procedures can be followed as what I think.
2. I use `.count()` of procedures, but it shows '`NoneType`' object has no attribute '`count`'.

```
data1=df.groupBy('_c0').agg(collect_list('_c1')).show()
print(data1.count())

data1=df.groupBy('_c0').apply(collect_list('_c1')).show()
```

I want to know how many number of rows and cols of procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data1=df.groupBy('_c0').apply(collect_list('_c1')).show()`

returns NoneType because `show` does not return anything. That is why you cannot apply count on it. Get rid of show. `apply` returns an sql.DataFrame. For what you are trying to do refer to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580782/pyspark-collect-set-or-collect-list-with-groupby)

Refer to [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5c55812400e1e0a8aaeb50a50be106e80c916c86/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L325) of `show`.

Comment: Thanks，It's helpful