# Implement `collect_list` via Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to implement the `collect_list` function is Spark.SQL.
The way to do it in PySpark via a dataframe is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38063180/3573203)

I am trying to do the same thing via a SQL query.

Comment: `spark.sql("select collect_list(col) from test group by col")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has little to do with pyspark or Spark with Scala.

Try this:

```
SELECT c1, collect_list(struct(c2, c3)) FROM tempview/table GROUP BY c1
```

or a variation based on your requirements.