# How to merge rows using SQL only?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can neither use pyspark or scala. I can only write SQL code.
I have a table with 2 columns item id, name.

```
item_id, name
1        name1
1        name2
1        name3
2        name4
2        name5
```

I want to generate results with the names of an `item_id` concatenated.

```
item_id,    names
1           name1-name2-name3
2           name4-name5
```

How do I create such a table with Spark sql?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyspark collect\_set or collect\_list with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580782/pyspark-collect-set-or-collect-list-with-groupby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of Spark SQL is that once you have a solution in any of the supported languages (Scala, Java, Python, R or SQL) you can *somewhat* figure out other variants.

The following SQL statement seems doing what you ask for:

```
SELECT item_id, array_join(collect_list(name), '-') as names 
FROM tableName
GROUP BY item_id
```

---

In `spark-shell` it gives the following result:

```
scala> sql("select item_id, array_join(collect_list(name), '-') as names from so group by item_id").show
+-------+-----------------+
|item_id|            names|
+-------+-----------------+
|      1|name1-name2-name3|
|      2|      name4-name5|
+-------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below -

```
df.orderBy('names', ascending=False)
    .groupBy('item_id')
    .agg(
        array_join(
            collect_list('names'),
            delimiter='-',
        ).alias('names')
    )
```

Comment: I can only use SQL

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spark data frame's groupBy and agg methods and concat_ws function:

```
df.groupBy($"item_id").agg(concat_ws("-", collect_list($"name")).alias("names")).show()
```

Group fields by `item_id` and aggregating each name field by concatenating them together.

Comment: I can only use SQL