# Convert a spark dataframe to a column

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` and I would like to convert it into a column: `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`.
So basically, this is my dataframe:
`val filled_column2 = x.select(first(("col1"),ignoreNulls = true).over(window))` that I want to convert, it into an sql spark column. Anyone could help on that ?
Thank you,

---

@Jaime Caffarel: this is exactly what i am trying to do, this will give you more visibility. You may also check the error msg in the 2d screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyspark collect\_set or collect\_list with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580782/pyspark-collect-set-or-collect-list-with-groupby)

Comment: @Olfa2 I have editedt the answer

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of the class [org.apache.spark.sql.Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html)

> A column that will be computed based on the data in a DataFrame. A new
> column is constructed based on the input columns present in a
> dataframe:
>
> df("columnName")            // On a specific DataFrame.
> col("columnName")           // A generic column no yet associcated
> with a DataFrame.    col("columnName.field")     // Extracting a
> struct field    col("`a.column.with.dots`") // Escape `.` in column
> names.    $"columnName"               // Scala short hand for a named
> column.    expr("a + 1")               // A column that is constructed
> from a parsed SQL Expression.    lit("abc")                  // A
> column that produces a literal (constant) value.

If `filled_column2` is a DataFrame, you could do:

```
filled_column2("col1")
```

******** EDITED AFTER CLARIFICATION ************

Ok, it seems to me that what you are trying to do is a JOIN operation. Assuming that the `product_id` is a unique key per each row, I would do something like this:

```
val filled_column = df.select(df("product_id"), last(("last_prev_week_nopromo"), ignoreNulls = true) over window)
```

This way, you are also selecting the product_id that you will use as key. Then, you can do the following

```
val promo_txn_cnt_seas_df2 = promo_txn_cnt_seas_df1
            .join(filled_column, promo_txn_cnt_seas_df1("product_id") ===  filled_column("driver_id"), "inner")
// orderBy("product_id", "week")... (the rest of the operations)
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: 'filled_column2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [first(col1) OVER (PARTITION BY x1 ORDER BY x2 ASC NULLS FIRST ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW): string]' .. this is filled_column2

Comment: What's the type of x on `val x = filled_column2("col1")`?