# Spark initialization error when using HiveContext in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Below are my codes. I faced a issue with `HiveContext`.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("jdf-dt-rtoc-withSQL").set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        SQLContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc); // The error occurred.

        //DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pairRDD,Pair.class);
        //DataFrame takenTogether1 = df.groupBy("fpart").agg(collect_list(col("rpart")));

        sc.stop();
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

My spark version is `1.6.0` and I found a thread ([Use collect_list and collect_set in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528966/use-collect-list-and-collect-set-in-spark-sql)) that I can use `collect_list` by importing `HiveContext`. However, when I tried it, it throw another error as below.

```
/usr/local/java/latest/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7536 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/usr/local/intellij/idea-IC-163.10154.41/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/local/java/latest/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/dst/02_Docu/01_Intellij_workspace/jdfdtrtocwithSQL/target/classes:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10/1.6.0/spark-core_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-mapred/1.7.7/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-ipc/1.7.7/avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-ipc/1.7.7/avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill_2.10/0.5.0/chill_2.10-0.5.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/kryo/2.21/kryo-2.21.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/reflectasm/reflectasm/1.07/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/esotericsoftware/minlog/minlog/1.2/minlog-1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.2/objenesis-1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.5.0/chill-java-0.5.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-asm5-shaded/4.4/xbean-asm5-shaded-4.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/2.2.0/hadoop-client-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.2.0/hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math/2.1/commons-math-2.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.2.0/hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.2.0/hadoop-hdfs-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-client-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-test-framework/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2/1.9/jersey-test-framework-grizzly2-1.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-test-framework/jersey-test-framework-core/1.9/jersey-test-framework-core-1.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.9/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-grizzly2/1.9/jersey-grizzly2-1.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-http/2.1.2/grizzly-http-2.1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-framework/2.1.2/grizzly-framework-2.1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/gmbal/gmbal-api-only/3.0.0-b023/gmbal-api-only-3.0.0-b023.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/external/management-api/3.0.0-b012/management-api-3.0.0-b012.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-http-server/2.1.2/grizzly-http-server-2.1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-rcm/2.1.2/grizzly-rcm-2.1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/grizzly/grizzly-http-servlet/2.1.2/grizzly-http-servlet-2.1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.servlet/3.1/javax.servlet-3.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.9/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.1/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.8.3/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.8.3/jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-guice/1.9/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-common/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/2.2.0/hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/2.2.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-annotations/2.2.0/hadoop-annotations-2.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-launcher_2.10/1.6.0/spark-launcher_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-network-common_2.10/1.6.0/spark-network-common_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-network-shuffle_2.10/1.6.0/spark-network-shuffle_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/fusesource/leveldbjni/leveldbjni-all/1.8/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.4.4/jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-unsafe_2.10/1.6.0/spark-unsafe_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.7.1/jets3t-0.7.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-recipes/2.4.0/curator-recipes-2.4.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-framework/2.4.0/curator-framework-2.4.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-client/2.4.0/curator-client-2.4.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.4.1/commons-math3-3.4.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.10/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.10/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.10.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/ning/compress-lzf/1.0.3/compress-lzf-1.0.3.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.2/snappy-java-1.1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/net/jpountz/lz4/lz4/1.3.0/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/roaringbitmap/RoaringBitmap/0.5.11/RoaringBitmap-0.5.11.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/2.2/commons-net-2.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-remote_2.10/2.3.11/akka-remote_2.10-2.3.11.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-actor_2.10/2.3.11/akka-actor_2.10-2.3.11.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/config/1.2.1/config-1.2.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.8.0.Final/netty-3.8.0.Final.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/uncommons/maths/uncommons-maths/1.2.2a/uncommons-maths-1.2.2a.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/akka/akka-slf4j_2.10/2.3.11/akka-slf4j_2.10-2.3.11.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.5/scala-library-2.10.5.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-jackson_2.10/3.2.10/json4s-jackson_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-core_2.10/3.2.10/json4s-core_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/json4s/json4s-ast_2.10/3.2.10/json4s-ast_2.10-3.2.10.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scalap/2.10.0/scalap-2.10.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.10.0/scala-compiler-2.10.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.9/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/mesos/mesos/0.21.1/mesos-0.21.1-shaded-protobuf.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.29.Final/netty-all-4.0.29.Final.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/clearspring/analytics/stream/2.7.0/stream-2.7.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-core/3.1.2/metrics-core-3.1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-jvm/3.1.2/metrics-jvm-3.1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-json/3.1.2/metrics-json-3.1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/io/dropwizard/metrics/metrics-graphite/3.1.2/metrics-graphite-3.1.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.4.4/jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.4.4/jackson-core-2.4.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-scala_2.10/2.4.4/jackson-module-scala_2.10-2.4.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.10.4/scala-reflect-2.10.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.6/paranamer-2.6.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/tachyonproject/tachyon-client/0.8.2/tachyon-client-0.8.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-hdfs/0.8.2/tachyon-underfs-hdfs-0.8.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-s3/0.8.2/tachyon-underfs-s3-0.8.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/tachyonproject/tachyon-underfs-local/0.8.2/tachyon-underfs-local-0.8.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/net/razorvine/pyrolite/4.9/pyrolite-4.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/net/sf/py4j/py4j/0.9/py4j-0.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/spark-project/spark/unused/1.0.0/unused-1.0.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-sql_2.10/1.6.0/spark-sql_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-catalyst_2.10/1.6.0/spark-catalyst_2.10-1.6.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/janino/janino/2.7.8/janino-2.7.8.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/janino/commons-compiler/2.7.8/commons-compiler-2.7.8.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-column/1.7.0/parquet-column-1.7.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-common/1.7.0/parquet-common-1.7.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-encoding/1.7.0/parquet-encoding-1.7.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-generator/1.7.0/parquet-generator-1.7.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-hadoop/1.7.0/parquet-hadoop-1.7.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-format/2.3.0-incubating/parquet-format-2.3.0-incubating.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/parquet/parquet-jackson/1.7.0/parquet-jackson-1.7.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-hivecontext-compatibility_2.10/2.0.0-preview/spark-hivecontext-compatibility_2.10-2.0.0-preview.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-hive_2.10/2.0.0-preview/spark-hive_2.10-2.0.0-preview.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/twitter/parquet-hadoop-bundle/1.6.0/parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.6.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-tags_2.10/2.0.0-preview/spark-tags_2.10-2.0.0-preview.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.10/2.2.6/scalatest_2.10-2.2.6.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/spark-project/hive/hive-exec/1.2.1.spark2/hive-exec-1.2.1.spark2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/javolution/javolution/5.5.1/javolution-5.5.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.4/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/antlr/stringtemplate/3.2.1/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/antlr/ST4/4.0.4/ST4-4.0.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/javaewah/JavaEWAH/0.3.2/JavaEWAH-0.3.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/iq80/snappy/snappy/0.2/snappy-0.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/net/sf/opencsv/opencsv/2.3/opencsv-2.3.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/spark-project/hive/hive-metastore/1.2.1.spark2/hive-metastore-1.2.1.spark2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/com/jolbox/bonecp/0.8.0.RELEASE/bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/derby/derby/10.10.2.0/derby-10.10.2.0.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-api-jdo/3.2.6/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-rdbms/3.2.9/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.5.4/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.4/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/javax/jdo/jdo-api/3.0.1/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.7/avro-1.7.7.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/calcite/calcite-avatica/1.2.0-incubating/calcite-avatica-1.2.0-incubating.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/calcite/calcite-core/1.2.0-incubating/calcite-core-1.2.0-incubating.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/calcite/calcite-linq4j/1.2.0-incubating/calcite-linq4j-1.2.0-incubating.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/net/hydromatic/eigenbase-properties/1.1.5/eigenbase-properties-1.1.5.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.3/joda-time-2.9.3.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/jodd/jodd-core/3.5.2/jodd-core-3.5.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/3.2.10/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/thrift/libthrift/0.9.2/libthrift-0.9.2.jar:/home/dst/.m2/repository/org/apache/thrift/libfb303/0.9.2/libfb303-0.9.2.jar:/usr/local/intellij/idea-IC-163.10154.41/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Main /home/dst/input/data2
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/02/22 21:40:01 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.0
17/02/22 21:40:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/02/22 21:40:01 WARN Utils: Your hostname, localhost.localdomain resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface eth1)
17/02/22 21:40:01 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/02/22 21:40:01 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: dst
17/02/22 21:40:01 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: dst
17/02/22 21:40:01 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(dst); users with modify permissions: Set(dst)
17/02/22 21:40:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 42363.
17/02/22 21:40:02 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
17/02/22 21:40:02 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
17/02/22 21:40:02 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.0.2.15:44169]
17/02/22 21:40:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 44169.
17/02/22 21:40:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/02/22 21:40:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/02/22 21:40:02 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-4a9159c9-d1c1-4e31-9837-0e4d1a2f7fe0
17/02/22 21:40:02 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 414.0 MB
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.0.2.15:4040
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 33443.
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 33443
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager localhost:33443 with 414.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 33443)
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SharedState
    at Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.2.15:4040
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/02/22 21:40:03 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-74fbf46d-55bc-4fb6-b8f3-edd4898e86e8
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bistel.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdf-dt-rtoc-withSQL</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hivecontext-compatibility_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-preview</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I want to use DF library such as `collect_list` and I found that I should use `HiveContext` on the Spark 1.6.0. However the error occurred even I followed this step.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` error because you are adding wrong dependency - "spark-hivecontext-compatibility_2.10". Your pom.xml file should have below dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: However, if I skip the `spark-hivecontext-compatibility_2.10` then `SQLContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc);` statement throw error, which uses `JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);`.

Comment: The error is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SharedState`. The statement of `SQLContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc);` throw the error above.

Comment: You will have to do clean build after adding the "spark-hive_2.10" dependency in pom.xml. It looks like it is still picking up old jar file. Check you local maven repository. If you are using eclipse then you can do Maven > Update Project.

Comment: I followed your comments but the result was same. I am using IntelliJ. I did invalidate cache/ Restart in Menu -> File and run my main function again. But I failed. And then, I build my code with Maven, then the jar file was successfully built . But I want to see the output result on the console so I want to run my codes,  not build them with maven.

Comment: "org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState" class is part of spark-sql 2.0 jar. You are using spark-sql 1.6.0 so you need spark-hive 1.6.0. Just check the spark jar file versions in your build environment.