# spark scala - Merge mutiple rows into one

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-1.6

I have a dataframe

```
|--id:string (nullable = true)
|--ddd:struct (nullable = true)
  |-- aaa: string (nullable = true)
  |-- bbb: long(nullable = true)
  |-- ccc: string (nullable = true)
  |-- eee: long(nullable = true)
```

I am having output like this

```
 id     |  ddd
--------------------------
   1    | [hi,1,this,2]
   2    | [hello,6,good,3]
   1    | [hru,2,where,7]
   3    | [in,4,you,1]
   2    | [how,4,to,3]
```

I want the expected o/p as:

```
   id   |  ddd
  --------------------
   1    | [hi,1,this,2],[hru,2,where,7]
   2    | [hello,6,good,3],[how,4,to,3]
   3    | [in,4,you,1]
```

Please help

Comment: Is that even possible ? Because you are just changing the structure of your column *dddd*, it becomes an array of struct with the aggregation

Comment: ok. can u give me the code please

Answer (score 8):

you can `collect_list` as following

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("ddd").as("ddd"))
```

`collect_set` works as well

```
df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_set("ddd").as("ddd"))
```

Comment: collect_list is not working .

Comment: whats the error . its working for me though

Comment: it says undefined function collect_list

Comment: i am using spark 1.6

Comment: Even with these two lines : import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ and 
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._ ?

Comment: Ah yeah you're right, import hive context maybe ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35528966/use-collect-list-and-collect-set-in-spark-sql

Comment: i didnt import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._  . When i type this in intellij, its disappearing