# Spark DataFrame serialized as invalid json

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**TL;DR**: When I dump a Spark `DataFrame` as json, I always end up with something like

```
{"key1": "v11", "key2": "v21"}
{"key1": "v12", "key2": "v22"}
{"key1": "v13", "key2": "v23"}
```

which is invalid json. I can manually edit the dumped file to get something I can parse:

```
[
  {"key1": "v11", "key2": "v21"},
  {"key1": "v12", "key2": "v22"},
  {"key1": "v13", "key2": "v23"}
]
```

but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something that would let me avoid this manual edit. I just don't now what.

**More details**:

I have a `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame` and I try dumping it to json using the following code:

```
myDataFrame.write.json("file.json")
```

I also tried with:

```
myDataFrame.toJSON.saveAsTextFile("file.json")
```

In both case it ends up dumping correctly each row, but it's missing a separating comma between the rows, and as well as square brackets.
Consequently, when I subsequently try to parse this file the parser I use insults me and then fails.

I would be grateful to learn how I can dump valid json. (reading the documentation of the [DataFrameWriter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#json(java.lang.String)) didn't provided me with any interesting hints.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an expected output. Spark uses [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/)-like format for a number of reasons:

- It can parsed and loaded in parallel.
- Parsing can be done without loading full file in memory.
- It can be written in parallel.
- It can be written without storing complete partition in memory.
- Is valid input even if file is empty.
- Finally `Row` in Spark is struct which maps to JSON object not array.
- ...

You can create desired output in a few ways, but it will always conflict with one of the above.

You can for example write a single JSON **document** for each partition:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df
  .groupBy(spark_partition_id)
  .agg(collect_list(struct(df.columns map col: _*)).alias("data"))
  .select($"data")
  .write
  .json(output_path)
```

You could prepend this with `repartition(1)` to get a single output file, but it is not something you want to do, unless data is very small.

1.6 alternative would be glom

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val newSchema = StructType(Seq(StructField("data", ArrayType(df.schema))))

sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  df.rdd.glom.flatMap(a => if(a.isEmpty) Seq() else Seq(Row(a))), 
  newSchema
)
```

Comment: Yeah. This won't work with such outdated version. a) https://stackoverflow.com/q/35528966/8371915 b) Because it doesn't support aggregations on structs. You'll have to use RDD for that.